# Web scraping embedded table created through external software

Tags: dataframe, web-scraping, extract, embedded-resource

I'm currently trying to pull all entries from the "Lookup lack of internet in your school district" table on this webpage https://www.courthousenews.com/distance-learning-poses-challenges-for-schools-and-families-during-outbreak/. That table has been created in Datawrapper - a visualization platform - so JavaScript hacks don't seem to be working.

Any ideas on how I can proceed will be much appreciated. Appropriate formatting of extracted data is not a necessity, but a way to cycle through the 1332 pages would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Scraped** the table from link https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/FJJmb/2/ available on the website which is used for embedding using `<iframe>` tag.

1. First finding the `script` tag which contains the **JSON** of schools
   data which is rendered in the table.
2. Then finding the exact data **JSON** '**chartData**' to sanitize and process the data as it is one long string.
3. Splitting the string where `\r` carriage return is present.
4. Replacing `\n` new line with blank in the string.
5. Finally saving the data related to schools in a **.csv** file.

> Do mention system path in file_path variable before running the script.

```
import json
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv
import re

def scrape_table_data():

list_of_schools = []
file_path = ''#mention your system path where you have to save the file
file_name = 'schools_list.csv'
url = 'https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/FJJmb/2/'

page = requests.get(url,verify=False)
soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.find_all('script', type='text/javascript',charset="utf-8")[5].text
txt = re.findall(r'chartData\s*:\s*(".*")', data)
sanitize_string = txt[0].split(r'\r')

csv_headers = ['#','School District','Pct. No internet','Pct. with internet','Pct. No computers']

for idx, school_data in enumerate(sanitize_string):
    if idx > 0:
        stripped_data = school_data.replace(r'\n', '').replace('\\', '').split(',')
        list_of_schools.append({
                                '#':idx,
                                'School District':stripped_data[0] + ',' + stripped_data[1],
                                'Pct. No internet': stripped_data[2],
                                'Pct. with internet': stripped_data[3],
                                'Pct. No computers': stripped_data[4]
                                })
       
with open(file_path + file_name ,'a+') as schools_CSV:
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(schools_CSV, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',fieldnames=csv_headers)

    print('Writing CSV header now...')
    csvwriter.writeheader()

    #iterate over the list and save the data in file
    for item in list_of_schools:
        print('Writing data rows now..')
        print(item)            
        csvwriter.writerow(item)

scrape_table_data()
```

There are 13315 records which were fetched and dumped in to the file. Below is a sample data screenshot.
[image: data screenshot]

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much for helping out!

Comment: Just did! Thanks again :)